# Cyclic subgroups of the center of a group

Tags: abstract-algebra

What are the conditions under which the center of a group will have a cyclic subgroup? (with proof, of course)

Comment: I should have said "a non-trivial cyclic subgroup" ie., a subgroup of order > 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always, certainly: if $\;Z(G)=1\;$ there's nothing to prove, and otherwise take any $\;z\in Z(G)\;$ and then $\;\langle z\rangle\;$ is a cyclic subgroup of the center.

In fact, we don't even need the first case $\;Z(G)=1\;$ .

Comment: WHY is any <z> a cyclic subgroup?

Comment: That is *the definition* of cyclic group, @user54301 : one that is generated by one single element: $$\langle z\rangle:=\{1,z,z^2,...\}\;$$ The group can be finite or infinite.

Comment: Suppose the order of the center of the group is infinite.  Now, choose any element z in the center. Why must z be cyclic?

Comment: @user54301, there is no such thing as "an element of a group is cyclic" : the group that **any** one and unique element of **any** group generates is cyclic.

Comment: Timbuc, yes of course you are correct.  I misstated my question.  I should asked, Why does an arbitrary element z in the center necessarily generate a non-trivial subgroup?

Comment: You seem to be assuming the center is not infinite.

Comment: @user54301, it doesn't matter what the center is: **any** element of **any** group generates a cyclic group (a subgroup of the bigger group). I think you''re not quite sure what a cyclic group is.

Comment: On re-reading I see your answers are completely correct. Unfortunately, I misstated my question which was meant to concern non-trivial finite cyclic groups of possibly infinite centers.  Will re-state in another question.

Answer (score 1):

Every nontrivial subgroup has a nontrivial cyclic subgroup. The condition is : the center is nontrivial.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:every group have a cyclic subgroup of order 1